# React Private Routes are not being redirected and they don't exist

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having those troubles about the private route and not being redirected. I'd like to know how to fix this code, please.

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Routes, Route, Swit } from 'react-router-dom';
import MasterLayout from '../src/layouts/admin/MasterLayout'

import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';


import Dashboard from './components/admin/Dashboard';
import Profile from './components/admin/Profiles';
import Login from './components/frontend/frontend/Auth/Login';
import Register from './components/frontend/frontend/Auth/Register';
import Home from './components/frontend/Home';
import AdminPrivateRoute from './AdminPrivateRoute';


import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

axios.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  config.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
  return config;
}
)

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />


          <Route path="/login" element={localStorage.getItem('auth_token') ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} >

          </Route>

          <Route path="/register" element={localStorage.getItem('auth_token') ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />} >

          </Route>
   
              <Route path="/admin/*" element={<AdminPrivateRoute />} >
              </Route>
          
            





        </Routes>

      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my AdminPrivateRoute.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Routes, Route, Swit } from 'react-router-dom';
import MasterLayout from './layouts/admin/MasterLayout';
import { Navigate,Outlet  } from 'react-router-dom';

function AdminPrivateRoute({ ...rest }) {

    return (

       

            <Routes>

                <Route {...rest}
                    render={({ props, location }) =>
                        localStorage.getItem('auth_token') ?
                            (<MasterLayout  {...props} />) :
                            (<Navigate to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: location } }} />)



                    }
                />
    
            </Routes>

       
    );
}
export default AdminPrivateRoute;
```

This is my route.js

```
import Dashboard from '../components/admin/Dashboard';
import Profile from '../components/admin/Profiles';
import Login from '../components/frontend/frontend/Auth/Login';
import Register from '../components/frontend/frontend/Auth/Register';


const routes = [
{path:'/admin',exact:true,name:'Admin'},
{path:'/admin/dashboard',exact:true,name:'Dashboard',component: Dashboard},
{path:'/admin/profile',exact:true,name:'Profile',component: Profile},
{path:'/admin/login',exact:true,name:'Login',component: Login},
{path:'/admin/register',exact:true,name:'Register',component: Register},

];


export default routes;
```

I'm following a tutorial about React ( older version) and I'm trying to change to React V6.
Finally, What for is  ...rest, render, locations, state from location? Can someone explain that block of code, in general, to understand what is happening.

Can you guide me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AdminPrivateRoute` component is certainly mixing up the older `react-router-dom` v5 syntax. In RRDv6 private "routes" are written to be wrapper components that render an `Outlet` (*or `children` if wrapping a single component*) or the `Navigate` component for redirection.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function AdminPrivateRoute() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return localStorage.getItem('auth_token')
    ? <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered here
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
}
```

Usage:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={localStorage.getItem('auth_token') ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />}  />
    <Route path="/register" element={localStorage.getItem('auth_token') ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />} />
    <Route element={<AdminPrivateRoute />} >
      {routes.map(({ path, component: Component }) => (
        <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
      ))}
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Note that the `AdminPrivateRoute` no longer spreads the rest of the passed props into a `rest` prop since passing props is no longer necessary. Similarly, the `render` prop is gone and we don't need to render a `Route` with the auth wrapper. Lastly, the `location` is the current location the user is attempting to access. The location is passed in route state to the authentication route so upon successful authentication the user can be redirected ***back*** to the original route they were trying access.

Comment: I got an error message when I added that code
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`."             
 .I'm checking the export of the PrivateAdminRoute and the import of this component in App.Js and It seems ok.   The error is here : "<Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />" , please, what is missing ?

Comment: @gian I didn't call it out, but when I destructured `component` I also renamed it to `Component` so it was a properly named React component. Is your code doing something similar?

Comment: Yes , I added your code block  " <Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />   .....,   etc. in App.Js

Comment: @gian Ok, I'll see if I can reproduce in a CodeSandbox and get back to you.

Comment: @gian Oh, you what, I think it's the missing component on the `"/admin"` path... I meant to filter that out or remove it from the `routes` config. Let me test.

Comment: @gianYes, confirmed (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-private-routes-are-not-being-redirected-and-they-dont-exist-4rucv). It's the route with missing component. You can either remove the entry or add a component to render for that path.